# Android - Issue with Main app having product flavors different than the dependant module

Tags: android, android-productflavors

So I have a android project with product flavor - flavor1/ flavor2

Now I need to add a dependent module to it with product flavors - flavor3/ flavor4.

This is how I am adding the dependency in build.gradle (app):

```
dependencies {
  .....
    implementation (project(':myModule')){
        transitive = false
    }
  ....
}
```

Now when I am building my android project with assembleFlavor1Debug, it gives me error:

```
Cannot choose between the following variants of project :myModule:
  - flavor3DebugRuntime
  - flavor3ReleaseRuntime
  - flavor4DebugRuntime
  - flavor4DebugRuntime

- Variant 'flavor3DebugAndroidTestCompile' capability mainApp:myModule:
      - Unmatched attributes:
          - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but no value provided.
          - Required default 'flavor1' but no value provided.
```

Comment: Can you share the gradle files of your main module and submodules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the library flavor I needed to be resolved in the main app as matchingFallback resolved the issue.

Main app build.gradle

```
    matchingFallbacks = ['flavor3']
```

With this while building the main app, since there is no matching flavour with the library, the app will select the library flavor - flavor 3